# I am doing a Solar System simulation, I have all the initial values and the drawings seem to be ok but, they dont move

Tags: lua, simulation, physics, modeling, love2d

This is my love.update(dt) function where I believe the problem is:

```
    function love.update(dt)
local  G = 6.67430e-11 -- gravitational constant
-- Force Between all the bodies 
for i, body in ipairs(bodies) do
 local fx = 0
  local fy = 0

 for j, body in ipairs(bodies) do
  if i ~= j then // skip calculation for the same body
            local dx = body.px - body.x
            local dy = body.py - body.y
            local dist = math.sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
            local f = G * body.mass * body.mass / dist^2
        
        theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
            fx = math.cos(theta) * f
            fy = math.sin(theta) * f
    return fx, fy
  end
   end
        
  body.ax = fx / body.mass
  body.ay = fy / body.mass

--Update of Velocity and Position
     for _, body in ipairs(bodies) do
    body.x = body.x + body.vx * dt + 0.5 * body.ax * dt^2
    body.y = body.y + body.vy * dt + 0.5 * body.ay * dt^2
    body.vx = body.vx + 0.5 * (body.ax + body.a0x) * dt
    body.vy = body.vy + 0.5 * (body.ay + body.a0y) * dt
    body.a0x = body.ax
    body.a0y = body.ay
end
end
```

I believe the problem might be in the for loop.

I used px to calculate the real values of dx in order to get the real values of f. After getting the values of f I could calculate fx and fy, and consequently the values of ax and ay. After that I could update the velocity and position of each object.
This is an example of the initial values:

```
   bodies[1] = {name = "sun", mass = 1.9891e30, radius = 696340000, x = width/2, y = height/2, vx = 0, vy = 0 , a0x= 0, a0y= 0, ax= 0, ay= 0}
   bodies[2]= {name = "mercury", mass = 0.3302e24, radius = 2440000, x = width/2 + 0.38*100, y =  height/2, vx = 0, vy = 48.92 * 1000, a0x= 0, a0y= 0, ax= 0, ay= 0, px = 46.0e9, py = 0}
```

I have tried :
`local dx = body.px - body.x`
`local dx = body2.px - body1.px`
`local dx = body.px - body.px`

I calculate dx and dy in order to find the distance between two bodies in the x and y directions.
In the context of simulating gravitational forces, we need to know the distance between each pair of bodies in order to calculate the force between them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the variable name in the nested loop to something different, like `other_body`, using the same name can cause it to be overwritten and creates confusion.

Comment: Will the loop recognize that I am referring to another object from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a return in the middle of your update? That basically kills your update before doing anything interesting. You may wanted to use `break`.

I assume you want to apply those fx/fy to the body. So the ax lines should be in the loop too I assume.

Please format the code, it helps a lot in seeing whats going on.

Comment: Thank you! So I should include the ax and then the return ?

Comment: It is rather unlikely you want a return in your main update function at all. In what case do you want to abort?

Comment: abort as in forgetting all the previous values? 
So it won't save the values and take them to the iteration of the next element